# Google chart display problem

Tags: url, visualization, google-visualization

Can you point out what is wrong in following query?
(Please copy and paste URL)

https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=550x200&chd=t:970,134,57,28,51,11,6&chl=Instant(970)|Below1Min(134)|Above1MinandBelow5Min(57)|Above5MinandBelow10Min(28)|Above10MinandBelow30Min(51)|Above30MinandBelow1Hr(11)|Above1HrsandBelow3Hrs(6)

I am getting

[image]

My Instant data is 970 and total is 1257 ie **77.17% but in chart it shows about 30%.**

Same problem for **Below 1 Minute Data**. It is 134 **(11.6%) but on chart it show about 25%**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [documentations](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html) says:

> However, when using text format data, **values greater than 100 are
>   trimmed to 100**, so you will need to
>   use text format with custom scaling to
>   display slices greater than 100
>   properly (use the chds parameter with
>   min/max values of
>   chds=0,max-slice-size).

And [here](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=550x200&chds=0,970&chd=t:970,134,57,28,51,11,6&chl=Instant%28970%29|Below1Min%28134%29|Above1MinandBelow5Min%2857%29|Above5MinandBelow10Min%2828%29|Above10MinandBelow30Min%2851%29|Above30MinandBelow1Hr%2811%29|Above1HrsandBelow3Hrs%286) is your chart with chds parameters.